# Send command to tty1 on startup

Tags: raspbian, boot, terminal

I've connected a Waveshare e-ink display to my Raspberry Pi 3B+ and installed [PaperTTY](https://github.com/joukos/PaperTTY). My idea is to run vim on the e-ink display and use it as a Freewrite-like device or a writerdeck. Basically, use it as a writing laptop.

In order to do that, I have to run a script at startup to send the tty1 output to the eink screen through PaperTTY, so I just created a shell script and through Startup Applications (running on Xfce GUI) it basically works perfectly. In order for it to be more seamless I had help and they recommended me to also use a sudo chvt 1 command on startup so I wouldn't need to do Ctrl + Alt + F1 manually. Now, my ideal would if, on top of that, I could start the vimWiki index on startup, automatically. Basically, the moment I boot up my laptop my eink display would show the vimWiki index.

However, the only options that I seem to know (running a [command] > /dev/tty1 and using sudo openvt -f 1 vim ~/writing/index.md) don't work. When using sudo openvt it basically scrambles the output of the screen. It does open vim and the file correctly, but any keyboard input seems to just put an incoherent mess on the screen.

If someone's curious about the whole conversation/issue, [you can find it here](https://github.com/joukos/PaperTTY/issues/114)

I hope I made myself clear, since it's very difficult for me to explain this properly as a non-english speaker.